# Verify android library's (aar) signature on runtime

Tags: android, signing, aar

I am developing an Android library which I am going to distribute to my business partners. I have signed it with my key store and I want to verify the signature on runtime to see if my library is recompiled using a different signature. But the normal way to verify the signature

```
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
(PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 
PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);)
```

in case of APK is not working as it returns only the application's signature and not the signature I signed my library with. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: were you able to figure out how to do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: @learner unfortunately no.